# Converting jQuery code into Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a page that has a lot of jQuery DOM manipulation code and I need to convert it all into Angular. Most of the jQuery code is about dealing with adjusting sizes of elements and setting classes and css properties. I am somewhat overwhelmed and need advice on how to proceed with converting that jQuery into Angular code. Important: the jQuery does not deal with business logic at all.

Here is an example of the jQuery code I need to convert:

```
var globals = {};

function init()
{
    globals.topNavHeight = $('.x').height() + $('.y').height();
}

function adjustSomeStuff()
{
    $('.topNav').css('height', globals.topNavHeight);
    $('.bottomFooter').css('someRandomProperty', $('#someHelperDomElem').css('height'));
    $('.anyOtherRandomElementOnPage').css('color', '#012345');
    globals.savedData = 1000;
}

$(window).bind('resize', adjustSomeStuff);
$(window).bind('load', init);
```

My problem is that I understand that I somehow need to convert those functions into directives, but they just use absolutely random elements from all over the page to do different calculations and stuff. Should I just throw out this code and write directives from scratch or can I make use of existing jQuery code in some way?

Comment: I have a hard time believing that the use of javascript for styling purposes is justified. It's possible, but unlikely. I would start there - find out how much of this you can do from css, and you'll probably find the port to Angular is quite a lot easier.

Comment: Well, I have a hard time believing in that either, but here we are... The page this JS is attached to is quite complex and has a lot of moving/hiding/popup/dynamic elements thus the JS looks like this - every function defined adjusts and readjusts several elements (mostly size and position) and CSS is already loaded with responsive stuff too. Not to mention - there are 3000 lines of such JS code that I need to process. I'm trying to extract all the 'easy' parts first but everything is so very tightly based on class names of elements from all around the page that it is very hard.

Comment: Sure, like I said, I realize that it's possible. I'd push heavily to bring the codebase to a place of health before attempting the move to Angular. You have my sympathy.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that cleaning up the jQuery code in the first place is a pretty good advice and I should do that before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

that specific code block that resizes the main page items based on the window size, i think can stay in jquery.
in angular you can define for example the css class (via ng-class) based on different data attributes, but it doesn't look like what you are doing.

HOWEVER, that color changes you have there should go to a css class and you should be switching css classes in runtime based on the application flow. that like i wrote before can be done in angular via ng-class (for example ng-class="{'warning': (issuesFound > 5), 'valid': (issuesFound == 0).....

Comment: The thing is that I basically want to do everything in Angular so that I do not need to support both jQuery DOM code and Angular at the same time. I am trying to simplify this jQuery code in order to make it managable. As for the 'color' properties - I agree that your example is the way to go, but the problem is that those color changes in the jQuery code do not depend on business logic at all. They are more like "if this div's height is bigger that 100px then the header color should be red".